# Dropbox requiring nautilus restart every boot after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, nautilus, dropbox

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. I had dropbox installed before the upgrade with no problems.

Now, every time I log in, dropbox prompts that nautilus requires reboot. I can do this fine and dropbox continues on its merry way, but it's annoying to do this every login.

I have uninstalled dropbox and reinstalled it, both from Software Centre and by using:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

No change to the prompts.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here. The answer below doesn't solve it in my case.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano In my case dropbox support said this is because ubuntu client doesn't support encrypted drives =| https://imgur.com/a/e6fSEX0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Dropbox from here: https://www.dropbox.com/install

Install the file by right click > Open with software install.

Or

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

for more info:

- [how to install a .deb file](https://askubuntu.com/a/841370/538619)
- [How to Install Dropbox on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/install-dropbox-ubuntu-16-04)